# Listener in a Content Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Let me explain my issue. I'm currently developing an Google Chrome Extension which inject a toolbar as an iframe in every web page.

The problem is that i need in some case to hide the toolbar, re-display it and things like that. Basicelly i was thinking to put my listener on my background-page, but it's useless because this page can't manipulate graphicely the object. So my plan was to put this listener on a content_script (who can manipulate graphiquely the objet). But the second problem is that a content-script in opposite to a background-page is not executed all the time but only once.

So i'm asking myself if it's possible to make a content-script sounds like a background-page, by putting a loop on it or something like that...

Thanks in advance.

I've tried this :

manifest.json

```
{   
    "background_page" : "background.html",
    "browser_action" :
    {
        "default_icon" : "images/extension.png"
        //"popup" : "activateToolbar.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": 
    [ {
          "all_frames": true,
          "css": ["css/yourtoolbar.css"],
          "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/yourtoolbar.js", "js/listener.js"],
          "matches": ["http://*/*"],
          "run_at": "document_end"
    } ], 
    "permissions" : ["tabs", "unlimitedStorage", "http://*/*", "notifications"],    
    "name" : "YourToolbar",
    "version" : "1.1",
    "description" : "Make your own Toolbar"
}
```

toolbar.html

```
<!-- Close Button -->
            <a href="javascript:hideToolbar()"><input type="image" src="images/close.png" name="close" width="18" height="18"></a>
```

Tool.js

```
function hideToolbar()
{
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({action : "hideToolbar"});
    window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('instantMessage.html', 'Ask Show Menu').show();
}
```

listener.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.action)
    {
        $('body').remove();
        console.log('Received Start');
        alert(request.action);
        console.log('Received End');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('nothing');
        alert('Not For Me [listener.js]');
    }
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
{   
    if(request.newTab) 
    {
        // Create a new Tab
        chrome.tabs.create({url: request.newTab});
    }
    else if(request.newWindow)
    {
        // Create a new Window
        chrome.windows.create({url: request.newWindow});
    }
    else if(request.action)
    {       
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs) {
          $.each(tabs, function() {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(this.id, {"action":"hideToolbar"} );
          });
        });
    }
});
```

But the problem is that the addListener didn't block the execution and he just didn't catch anything...

Comment: Can you please show how you are sending the requests to this content script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send a request from a background page to a content script you need to use [`chrome.tabs.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html) (not `chrome.extension.sendRequest`) and provide tab id.

In a content script you don't need to periodically create `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener`, just create it once and it will be there permanently.

**EDIT**

To send a request from a content script you need to run `chrome.extension.sendRequest` there and add `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` to a background page.

Comment: But you tell me how to "send a request from a background page to a content script"

An i want to sent a request from content script to background page...

Comment: @Sindar Then why do you create a listener in a content script and sending a request from a background page? You need to switch it all around then.

Comment: @Serg I'm not sure you understand what i want. To be clear, chrome.extension.sendRequest({action : "hideToolbar"}); call my listener(content script).

That's what i want but it didn't work, here there is no interaction with the background-page. You had understand that ?

So i want to make a listener like in my content-script file "listener.js".

Comment: @Sindar Sorry I don't understand. Why did you put `addListener` in a content script if you want to send requests **from** a content script, not **to** it? In this case you need to put `addListener` in a background page and send requests from a content script using `sendRequest`.

Comment: @Serg Well, i don't send request from contentScript. If you look i send the request from Tool.js, this file is not a contentscript, it's just a simple javascript file with a couple of function.

Comment: Why not listen to serg :) In your manifest run_at should be "document_end" and your content script should have just the listener and the DOM injection.

Comment: I've making modification in the code. So, if i've well understand, i have to change the document_start to document_end.

The Tool.js send a request to the background_page and the background_page call all tabs to communicate with the listener.js ?

Comment: For those coming to this answer recently, this API is now deprecated.  Developers should use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`.